# How to set rules for commit message with Husky?

Tags: husky

This is the first time I use [Husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky), after reading the documentation, I did not find a solution for my issue.

I want to set a convention for the commit messages:

1. Must start with Capital.
2. Must have more than 20 characters.

How to apply these rules and let husky reject any commit that does not follow them?

Comment: Not sure if this will do what you want, but [DangerJS](https://danger.systems/js/) might work.